# Как удалять инлайн клавиатуру после нажатия aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
menu1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Боты", callback_data='bots')
menu_in.insert(menu1)

menu2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Скоро...", callback_data='ass')
menu_in.insert(menu2)

cancel_menu = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="cancel")
menu_in.insert(cancel_menu)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'bots')
async def callback(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        reply_markup=feel_bots,
        text="Вы выбрали: <b>Боты</b>", parse_mode='html')

feel_bots=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
    InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="Telegramm Bot",
        callback_data="feel_tgbot",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()))

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'feel_tgbot')
async def callbacks(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        reply_markup=telegrammBOTSTG,
        text="Бот ", parse_mode='html')


telegrammBOTSTG = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Заказать", url=TelegramMy)
    ]
])
```

Как сделать что бы при нажатий клавиатура скрывалась?

Answer (score 0):

Просто не отправляйте `reply_markup`, если в сообщении не должна быть Inline-клавиатура. ReplyKeyboardRemove() - удаляет обычные кнопки, не инлайн.

Если я правильно понял, исходя из Вашего кода, то примерно выглядеть это должно вот так:

```py
feel_bots=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Telegramm Bot", callback_data="feel_tgbot")
)
```